# Python operators produces a strange output

Tags: python

Why does this code

> `2--2`

produces this output

> `4`

in python specifically?

Comment: `2--2` is equivalent to `2 - (-2)`, which is `4`. This isn't python specific behavior.

Comment: What output are you expecting from this?

Comment: Why is this strange? What were you *expecting*?

Answer (score 0):

Because the operator is reading `2--2` as:

`2` (plus) `negative` `negative` `2`

Remember that two negatives equal a positive. This can also be understood as:

`2` + `(-1)`* `(-1)` * (`2`) = `2` + `(1)` * `2` which equals to `2` +`2` = 4

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @b_c it's a simple math problem and not specific to python.

you can replicate the behavior in Java, JS or any other language. But sometimes you need to make sure to use proper spacing.
For example in JS
`2--2` will throw an error but `2 - -2` will yield an answer of 4.